# Change default settings used by gallery shortcode

Tags: filters, shortcode, gallery

I need to change the default gallery shortcode settings so that "columns" = 5 & "link" = 'file'.

Which filter to add to the file `functions.php`?

Source code:

```
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'order'      => 'ASC',
            'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
            'id'         => $post ? $post->ID : 0,
            'itemtag'    => $html5 ? 'figure'     : 'dl',
            'icontag'    => $html5 ? 'div'        : 'dt',
            'captiontag' => $html5 ? 'figcaption' : 'dd',
            'columns'    => 3,
            'size'       => 'thumbnail',
            'include'    => '',
            'exclude'    => '',
            'link'       => ''
    ), $attr, 'gallery' );
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`shortcode_atts_{$shortcode}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/) filter allows default parameters to be modified for shortcodes.

To modify the `[gallery]` shortcode, we'll use the `shortcode_atts_gallery` filter.

Here is an example that changes the defaults for the `columns` and `link` parameters in the `[gallery]` shortcode. Note that if the user specifies values for these parameters, those values will be used; we're just changing the defaults.

```
add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_gallery', 'wpse246345_shortcode_atts_gallery', 10, 4 );
function wpse246345_shortcode_atts_gallery( $out, $pairs, $atts, $shortcode ) {

    if ( ! isset( $atts['columns'] )  ) {
        $out['columns'] = 5;
    }

    if ( ! isset( $atts['link'] ) ) {
        $out['link'] = 'file';
    }   

    return $out;
}
```